# List dictionaries in documentation with Sphinx

Tags: python, dictionary, python-sphinx, autodoc

I have a project with a few .py files that only contains a few dictionaries. Like this:

```
# My file
dictionary = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2: 'value2'}
```

But much larger and longer and I would like to document this with Sphinx but I can't get it to work properly.

The files are found by Sphinx just fine and show up under Modules as folder.file but they are all empty? What am I doing wrong? Why won't the dictionaries show up?

in the .rst file for the folder it shows:

```
    folder.file module
--------------------

.. automodule:: folder.file
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:
```

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/27875455/407651

Answer (score 2):

Sphinx does require extra docstrings for all members that are not classes or methods. You probably don't want to edit `autodoc` (even though this can come handy for individualization under certain conditions), you can overcome this issue by adding a docstring **below** the variable:

```
# My file
dictionary = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
'''A dictionary containing secret values.

Do not expose this dictionary's values to the public. By default, the 
keys 'key1' and 'key2' are available.'''
```

Comment: You also can add comment before the dictionnary with this format: `#: <comment text>`. but this is single line comment and the `#: ` has to be repeated for each line. http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autodoc.html#directive-autoattribute