# alabaster how to render parameters with fixed-font

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

## Edit#1

made some progress, but still not get it:
I managed to use mono font by tweaking my `custom.css` like this:

```
em.property{
  font-family: 'Consolas', 'Menlo', 'DejaVu Sans Mono', 
'Bitstream Vera Sans Mono', monospace;
}
```

I indeed have a mono-space font now, but triple quotes are still messy:

[image]

## Initial Question:

I generate my project's documentation using `autodoc` (alabaster theme for now, but I could change). I have an issue with the rendering of my classes parameters.

source:

```
class CBUSH(SimpleCard):
"""
Generalized Spring-and-Damper Connection
Defines a generalized spring-and-damper structural element that may be nonlinear
or frequency dependent.

ref: NX Nastran 12 Quick Reference Guide 11-39 (p.1399)
"""

TABLE = """
| 1     | 2   | 3    | 4  | 5  | 6     | 7  | 8  | 9   | 10 |
|-------+-----+------+----+----+-------+----+----+-----+----|
| CBUSH | EID | PID  | GA | GB | GO/X1 | X2 | X3 | CID |    |
|       | S   | OCID | S1 | S2 | S3    |    |    |     |    |
"""
GIDS_PATTERN = re.compile('^G[A|B]$')
DEFAULTS = {'S': 0.5, 'OCID': -1}
```

rendered as:

[image]

So, the question is: how to set parameters description font to mono space font?

From code source, i saw that the balises used to render those items are `<code class="descname">TABLE</code><em class="property">`, so I tried to create a `static/custom.css` with the following code:

```
tt.property{
  font-family: 'Consolas', 'Menlo', 'DejaVu Sans Mono', 'Bitstream Vera Sans Mono', monospace;
}
```

but so far, nothing worked.

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/54823758/407651.