# Indenting Items When Printing From a File

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am still in the process of learning Python so this may seem like a basic question.  I am working through the sample problems out of Python Crash Course.  I am attempting to read multiple files and print out/display the contents of each file.  I want to have the text "The file contains the following pet names: " print and then have an indented list of the names below.

I'm running into an issue of either only the first item/line in each file indenting or each letter of a line printing on its own individual line.

Here is the code I wrote.

```
def list_pets(filename):
    """Lists pet names within the file."""
    try:
        with open(filename) as file_object:
            pet_names = file_object.read()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        msg = "Unable to locate file " + filename + "."
        print(msg)
    else:
        print("\nThe file " + filename + " contains the following pets: ")
        pets = ""
        for pet in pet_names:
            pets += pet
        print(pets)

filenames = ['dogs.txt', 'cats.txt', 'birds.txt']
for file in filenames:
    list_pets(file)
```

Here is the output of the above code (birds.txt was intentionally not in the folder):

```
The file dogs.txt contains the following pets:
Buttons
Biscuit
Abby
Sam
Jerry
Obi
Roger


The file cats.txt contains the following pets:
Missy
Brown Cat
Oliver
Seal
Mr Bojangles

Unable to locate file birds.txt.
```

How can I use \t to indent the names?  I've tried changing `print(pets)` to `print("\t" + pets)` but that seems to only indent the first name.

Thanks in advance!  I'm having a lot of fun learning Python but this little booger has me stumped.

Comment: See [How to indent the contents of a multi-line string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234274/how-to-indent-the-contents-of-a-multi-line-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 ...
 pet_names = file_object.readlines()  # to split the lines
 ...


 for pet in pet_names:
     pets = pets + "\t" + pet +"\n"
 print(pets)
```

just add `\t` before each name and a new line after

Comment: I updated my code to this:

       `print("\nThe file " + filename + " contains the following pets: ")
        pets = ""
        for pet in pet_names:
            pets = pets + "\t" + pet
        print(pets)`

and got the following:

Comment: `The file dogs.txt contains the following pets:
        B       u       t       t       o       n       s
        B       i       s       c       u       i       t
        A       b       b       y
        S       a       m
        J       e       r       r       y
        O       b       i
        R       o       g       e       r
`

Sorry, the formatting is weird.  It put a tab between each letter of the names.

Comment: This latest iteration still prints each letter on it's own line but at least each letter is indented!  We're halfway there!  I appreciate the help!

Comment: change `pet_names = file_object.read()` to `pet_names = file_object.readline()` and check

Comment: now if changing gives you an extra line after each name then remove the `\n` from my code.

Comment: I swapped readline to readlines and kept this chunk:
`for pet in pet_names:
            pets += "\t" + pet
        print(pets) `

It worked!

Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm not sure what the proper etiquette is.  But I really appreciate your help.  I was wracking my brain over this one.

Comment: Ahhh!  If you change it so show `readlines()` instead of `read()`, that's what did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, and see if the tab reports properly:

```
_list = ["Buttons","Biscuit","Abby","Sam","Jerry","Obi","Roger"]

indent = "\t"
for l in _list:
    print("{}{}".format(indent, l))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you print **pet_names** just after you *read()* it- you'll see they all still prints in new line each. That's because **read()** does not remove line breaks.
Also, use format() to format strings. Good luck!

```
def list_pets(filename):
"""Lists pet names within the file."""
try:
    with open(filename) as file_object:
        pet_names = file_object.read().split('\n')
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("Unable to locate file {}.".format(filename))
else:
    print("The file {} contains the following pets: {}".format(filename, ' ,'.join(pet_names)))
```