# How to print multi-line outputs (like pandas data frames and such) with indents

Tags: python, pandas

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234274/how-to-indent-the-contents-of-a-multi-line-string) shows how one might print multi-line strings with indents, but it doesn't work for pandas outputs.

Take the following example:

```
d = pd.DataFrame(dict(x = list(range(10)), y = list(range(10))))
print(f"\t{d}")
```

yields:

```
       x  y
0  0  0
1  1  1
2  2  2
3  3  3
4  4  4
5  5  5
6  6  6
7  7  7
8  8  8
9  9  9
```

I want it to indent the whole table, not just the first two lines.  Is there an easy way to do this without complicated parsing?

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```py
>>> print('\t' + str(d).replace('\n', '\n\t'))
       x  y
    0  0  0
    1  1  1
    2  2  2
    3  3  3
    4  4  4
    5  5  5
    6  6  6
    7  7  7
    8  8  8
    9  9  9
```

Now there is probably a prettier way to do it but this one is pretty simple and ready to understand (replace new line by new line + tab)

**EDIT**
A little less "hacky", where you can handle every lines the same way:

```py
print('\n'.join(f'\t{line}' for line in str(d).split('\n')))
```

Works by splitting every line into a value, modifying that value and then joining them again into a single string

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a `.to_string()`, method.  Do that then use the method in the linked question:

```
import textwrap
def indent(text, amount, ch=' '):
        return textwrap.indent(text, amount * ch)
d = pd.DataFrame(dict(x = list(range(10)), y = list(range(10)))).to_string()
print(f"{indent(d, 4)}")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is to_json() method on the dataframe https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html#pandas-dataframe-to-json :

```
    print(d.to_json(indent=4))
```